# IE 11 Javascript blocking key combinations doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have the code below which works for all browsers EXCEPT IE 11 - I need a solution for IE 11 - it is absolutely imperative.  Can anyone help with this?  The combination of keys (i.e., checking event.ctrlKey and any other key does not work).  However, if I put an alert box in the JS function, it DOES work, I have no idea why!  Without the alert, it seems to allow combinations like ctrl+p ctrl+o pass right through (i.e., not blocking/cancelling the keys).

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        //disable keys: ctrl, alt, esc, F1 to F12
        var forbiddenKeys = [17,18,27,91,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123];
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}};
            console.log("HERE", e);
            if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey || e.altKey || $.inArray(e.which, forbiddenKeys !== -1)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? This sounds user-hostile.

Comment: It's not user hostile - it's simply trapping any ctrl/meta/alt keys for a CAS-enabled login page that is in KIOSK mode.

Comment: You know that frameworks like jQuery abstract away all the cross browser stuff.  Just use the `e` object being passed into your event handler to get the key code, prevent default, stop propagation, etc. Your code could be shortened to about 10 lines.  Also, it seems reasonable that a browser won't let you block the use of CTRL and ALT keys.  They are essential to many users who may want to ALT+TAB away from crappy websites.

Comment: The user is not allowed to navigate anywhere outside of this ONE page - (kiosk mode).  It works in all other configurations except for IE 11 - which is a killer because that's what most of the kiosk terminals have just upgraded to1

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your reply.  I had actually tried that initially, as you suggested I really had only about 10 lines of code.  I put the other stuff (if window.event...etc ) just to ensure that there wasn't anything funky going on.  Turns out that it doesn't make any difference.  As I said - if I put an alert box anywhere in the function, the ctrl key is successfully blocked.  Without the alert - does NOT block

Comment: I also tried the following:  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9"> at the top of the page right after the <html> element - no effect :(

Comment: `meta` tags go in the `head` element.

Comment: So your code above doesn't work in Chrome/Mac for me.  But the very short version using jQuery to do all the work does: http://jsfiddle.net/45m4gv7h/1/

Comment: Thanks Alexander - i moved the meta tag to after the <head> - still no luck - ctrl-P/ctrl-O still are not blocked as they should be - all other browsers are blocking this (as I've mentioned numerous times)

Comment: Ryan - thanks - I'm trying it now.

Comment: Whoops, there is a bug in my code.  I had a misplaced parenthesis.  Please use this: http://jsfiddle.net/45m4gv7h/2/.  Also worth noting that I'm still able to CMD + Tab away from my browser because you can't prevent OS level key combinations.  I can**not** however save (CMD + S), open developer tools (ALT + CMD + J), or any other browser-related stuff like that.

Comment: Ryan - did you try the code in IE 11?  My previous code worked in all browsers (made some test adjustments just for IE 11 test/deploy but the bottom half worked in all other browsers)

Comment: this is a known bug in IE11
canceldefault has no effect with
ctrl+s

Comment: this is a known bug in IE11
canceldefault has no effect with
ctrl+s, ctrl+p, ctrl+o in IE11, other injuns also have ctrl key combinations that cannot be cancelled. You can remap the alt key combinations of the IE menu by placing <a accesskey="f"></> keys fevath....... at the top of your document.

Comment: HI Rob, thanks for your reply - is there any place that documents this issue to your knowledge?  I will need to provide some supporting documentation as to why this won't work in IE 11 and try to come up with a workaround... thanks much!

Comment: Ryan - I tried your code (thanks) in IE 11 - still not working.  Could be because of what Rob mentioned.

Comment: I found at least a bug report for this here: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/1046712

Comment: thanks janfoeh.  I tried the workaround, didn't work for me. :(